# Insertar un dato int en postgresql desde java

Tags: java

Estoy desarrollando un programa de facturacion, necesito insertar un dato tipo `int` pero me sale error este es la linea:

```
Item ite = new Item();
ite.setPrecio(txt_precio.getText());
```

Comment: Hola Nicolas, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Has de especificar el error. Seguramente sea que te falta convertir el `string` del `getText` a un `int`. Prueba a usar `parseInt` y si tienes algun problema concreto, explicalo en la pregunta, siguiendo [ask]. Un saludo.

Comment: @Nicolas Mosquera Espinosa cual es el error que te esta dando.

Comment: Intente con un ite.setPrecio(Integer.parseInt(txt_precio.getText()));

Comment: muchas gracias a todos era convertirlo a string, ya puse la linea de raul y me sirvio, ahora para guardarlo a la bd postgres me sale este error        Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "67.009" el campo es txt_precio y quiero guardarlo con el punto para luego sumar todos los productos y en el txt_total salga la sumatoria.

Comment: Ahí el problema es estas guardando en un campo integer un tipo double o float

Comment: Revisa la documentación de postgresql puede ser un decimal o un float

Comment: Ya cambie el tipo de dato a Double y ya hice la conversion en el textfield pero me guarda 22.6, no se como buscar la forma de que me guarde el valor completo 22.600 gracias por su ayuda Señor Raul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error esta en que intentando guardar un String en un campo Double.

Te dejo información de como hacer el `parseDouble` [Double](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29)

Este seria un ejemplo

```
String texto = "22.600"; // example String
double valor = Double.parseDouble(texto);
```

Y con tu codigo seria

```
double valor = Double.parseDouble(txt_precio.getText());
ite.setPrecio(valor);
```

Comment: muchas gracias.

Comment: De nada espero te sirva